# Unsupervised classification - verification of clusters

Tags: r, clustering, k-means, validation

Not sure if this is best placed here but I will have a go.

I am working with clinical data in order to stratify patients using different biomarkers. I have log transformed and MinMax normalised all variables for the 1200 patients.

After plotting a heatmap, it would seem some individuals do cluster together, and biologically the phenotypes identified are meaningful.

[image]

Despite this PCA does not show any such clustering and instead shows a large agglomeration of individuals. K-means identifies the best number of clusters (if any) to be 3 (based on elbow method)

A silhouette plot also indicates that the the patients are very close to/on the neighbouring decision boundaries with an average coefficient  of 0.21 with 3 clusters.

[image]

My question is - is it ok to separate patients on the basis of these statistics? We would like to separat them as biologically/clinically they behave different, and it seems there may be some difference here too. Equally, it is of course important the the plot is correct and I do not "force" the patients into different groups out of wont.

Any input is much appreciated!

Comment: Why have you applied min/max rescaling instead of zscores?

Comment: Just out of choice. I also experimented with tanhEstimation. Would you consider mimax to be wrong?

Comment: I don't mean to sound like a dork but "unsupervised clustering" is redundant term. You should either call it "unsupervised classification" or simply "clustering".

Comment: youre right - changed

Comment: Also, do you have something specific you're trying to observe in your clustering output or is it a purely untargeted approach? If you have any kind of metric to quantify what you are trying to observe in your clusters, you can then apply ANOVA with post-hoc testing to see whether the pairwise comparison of means between your clusters are significant for that metric.

Comment: I think you ought to make some explanation of the silhouette plot since you show it. For people to understand it.

Comment: @ttnphns - Maybe [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silhouette_(clustering)) can be a start. The silhouette plot is fine for a nontargeted analysis but is certainly insufficient for a scientific work where the statistical significance of a domain-specific metric is required. For the latter scenario, more advanced methods are required and GLM are common practice.

Comment: @Digio broadly speaking its non-targeted. I have some labels which I have used to measure significance using mann-whitney U (pVal 0.04). The problem is that these metrics are not ideal (hence looking for different clusters)

Comment: @Digio, "unsupervised classification" is a paradox, unsupervised learning being more accurate. About rescaling, minmax rescaling flattens outliers, which is ok if you don't care about those. Z-Scores preserve the distribution.

Comment: @g3o2 - Well, that's just your personal opinion. The fact is that ['unsupervised classification'](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/clustering) is a mainstream term en a par with 'unsupervised learning'.

Comment: The terms being supposedly mainstream does not remove the paradox.

Comment: @g3o2 thanks for your reply RE normalisation. Ive had a slight internal battle making sure what ive done is ok. In this particular case, "high" is high so outliers are just an extreme version of those. I also tried using percentiles which of course gives a uniform distribution, but decided against.

Comment: @g3o2 - Naturally, everyone has the right to stick to their personal point of view.

Comment: @JB1  Notice that the dendrogram on your heatmap was probably produced by hierarchical clustering and seems to show 6 clusters,  not 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't *rely* on cluster analysis.

Because a single additional data point often can cause a very different result, unfortunately. Try removing a few samples, then rerun your clustering and compare the results! Judging from your Silhouette, I don't think clustering "worked" on this data (and beware that k-means will always find k clusters, even on uniform data!) - your preprocessing may not yet be good enough.

Treat it as a hypothesis generator instead.

You ran clustering, and you got three clusters. This is now your working hypothesis, that you need to **verify with experiments**. You likely will also need to *formalize* it first, before you can do experiments: what is different between these groups, and how can we classify new data into the correct group. I wouldn't be surprised if you find you only need to treat one cluster special, and several clusters should be one.

Comment: Thanks @Anony-Mousse. I think this was actually the answer i was looking for to reassure me that i was not missing some vital information. What I have found (possible clusters) appears to be interesting clinically, and it is this that I should explore and use to develop further :)